# How to execute a standalone java program in play 2.2.1 using java command

Tags: java, shell, playframework-2.0

I've a standalone java program file "SyncBuildSIDMODUpdates.java" having main method defined in it, that reads a file, processes it and update the database based on the output. and this is part of the Play framework classes.

Now I've a shell script(which is placed in the same server where the play framework is installed) written to invoke "SyncBuildSIDMODUpdates.java" using the standard java command "java SyncBuildSIDMODUpdates" from the location {play_installed_dir}/target/scala-2.10/classes/jobs.

But I'm getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SyncBuildSIDMODUpdates (wrong name: jobs/SyncBuildSIDMODUpdates)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I need to execute that java program through that shell script as per the application behavior. Can someone tell me how we do it? Should I export the classpath or something? what is going wrong?

Thanks,
Madhu

Comment: Put some effort for valid formatting pls

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't get you.. should i add some java code ??

Comment: reading block of logs without StackOverflow formatting features is hard and nobody wants to waste time on 'decoding' it, use available Help section over the editor window to make it readable

Comment: My issue is resolved.. Thanks... Command is: play "run-main jobs.SyncBuildSIDMODUpdates"